# eigenvalues of the symmetric part of a block Jordan

Tags: matrices

Assume that $0$ is an eigenvalue of matrix $A$. Let $J_k(0)$ be a Jordan block of size $k\times k$ associated with $0$. What is the eigenvalues of $$\frac{J_k(0)+J_k(0)^T}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a [circulant matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), of the form
$$
\frac12\pmatrix{0&1&0 \\1&0&1&\ddots\\0&1&0\\&\ddots&&\ddots}
$$
the wiki page also has an explicit formula for the eigenvalues.

Comment: Do you mean (Toeplitz) [tridiagonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix)?